# FinderSync Extension runtime error: The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: swift, cocoa, sandbox, nsfilemanager, findersync

I'm writing a FinderSync extension that places an item in the context menu. When I right-click, I want the title of the menu item to change based on the selected file's contents. However, when I try to read the contents using `Data(contentsOf: selectedUrl)`, it throws the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Some File.png” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/Shared/MySyncExtension Documents/Some File.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x61800004cf00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

This does not change if I add or remove sandboxing.

---

#### Prior Research

- [The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23774731/3939277)

  - The compiler has always been set to the default
- [Read and Write access for FinderSync extension in a sandboxed environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30276155/3939277)

  - The entitlement is enabled. Also, this manifests with sandboxing turned off.
- ["File could not open because you do not have permission to view it." | Official Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3198038?tstart=0)

  - The file's permissions say "everyone" has "Read only" access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the Sandbox is preventing file access to the file, and thus your app cannot open it.

[Read and Write access for FinderSync extension in a sandboxed environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276155/read-and-write-access-for-findersync-extension-in-a-sandboxed-environment)

Even though the Finder Sync App Extension is granted "User Selected File" Sandbox File Access, the files accessed by the user via right-click seemingly do not count as being "user-selected".

It may be possible to guide the user to [select a root directory via an NSOpenPanel via Powerbox, after which all subdirectories can be accessed via a security-scoped bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

Using a Temporary Exception entitlement is also a possibility, but will cause App Review problems:

[Is there any way to give my sandboxed Mac app read only access to files in ~/Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952225/is-there-any-way-to-give-my-sandboxed-mac-app-read-only-access-to-files-in-lib)

Please duplicate my Apple bug report requesting this behavior be allowed:

> Finder Sync App Extension `selectedItemURLs()` should receive "User Selected File" Sandbox file access.
>
> rdar://42874694
>   https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5063363058991104